# How to use the CASE condition to filter double data?

Tags: sql, function, case

first try at Stack for me, feel free to feedback if I don't match the asking codes on here.

I'm working within a table with financial information and numerous revenues, at different closing dates.

I'd like to return the ID, the closing date, the latest revenue.

To achieve this I did

```
SELECT A.ID, A.closing_date,A.operating_revenue_
From financials A

INNER JOIN(
      SELECT ID, max(closing_date) as Latest_Date
      FROM financials
      GROUP BY ID
)tm on A.ID=tm.ID and A.closing_date=tm.Latest_Date
```

Now my issue is that I have double data depending on the consolidation code in the financial data. I happen to have the uncosolidated and consolidated data at the same date, the codes are U1,C1.

Do you have any idea on how I could, if I have data for both codes, just retrieve the consolidated one?
[The issue appears at 31 and 32](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOdhJ.png)

I'm trying things with the CASE function:

````
WHERE A.consolidation code in ('C1','U1')
AND (Case A.consolidation_code in 'U1' or 'C1', then 'C1'
ELSE 'U1'
END)
```

The latest seems the issue, has anyone an idea of what is the issue and how I could solve it?
Thank you


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOdhJ.png
````

Comment: Sample data would greatly help your question.

Comment: If your DBMS supports `row_number() over()` do use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `row_number() over()` and assuming `ID, closing_date, operating_revenue_ , consolidation_code` is unique key and building on the fact `'C1'` < `'U1'`

```
select A.ID, A.closing_date,A.operating_revenue_
from (
    select f.*, row_number() over(partition by ID, closing_date, operating_revenue_ order by consolidation_code) rn
    from financials f
    where consolidation_code in ('C1','U1')
) A
where a.rn = 1
```